# Merge two numerical string

Tags: mysql, sql

MYSQL command:

```
UPDATE `tbl_objednavka` SET
`TOTAL` = '6300',
`EANS` = CAST('8433611369655;' AS char)+CAST(`EANS` AS char),
`COUNTS` = CAST('1;' AS char)+CAST(`COUNTS` AS char)
WHERE `ID_OBJEDNAVKA`=2;

_____________________________________
|                 |                 |
|      EANS       |     COUNTS      |
+-----------------+-----------------+
|                 |                 |
|  8433611364094  |        1        |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

It for some weird reason '8433611369655;' dont merge strings but add one number to the other so I get something as this: 1.6867223e+13...
I need to get an array, so this: 8433611369655;8433611364094 in EANS and 1;1 in COUNTS

I can use php for this, but I would love to do this using SLQ only

Comment: `+` is for adding numbers, use the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using MySQL, so you want to use `concat()` rather than `+` for string concatenation.

Also, you should *never* convert values to `char()` without a length.  In this case, though, I think `varchar()` would be a more appropriate type.

However, I would suggest this query:

```
UPDATE `tbl_objednavka`
    SET `TOTAL` = '6300',
       `EANS` = concat('8433611369655;', `EANS`),
       `COUNTS` = concat('1;', `COUNTS`)
    WHERE `ID_OBJEDNAVKA`=2;
```

You don't seem to need the casts at all.  The types of `EANS` and `COUNTS` should be character to begin with, because you are assigning character values to them.

If they are numeric, then you need to alter the table so they can hold the values you want.  In practice, I would suggest adding new columns in this case.  Or, using a view to create the new columns.

Comment: It can have multiple of eans and I don't want them in one more separate table... but yes it would be more correct and it would folow the nominal form

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `tbl_objednavka` SET
`TOTAL` = '6300',
`EANS` = CONCAT('8433611369655;', CAST(`EANS` AS char)),
`COUNTS` = CONCAT('1;', CAST(`COUNTS` AS char))
WHERE `ID_OBJEDNAVKA`=2;
```

MySQL doesn't use `+` for string concatenation, you have to use the `CONCAT()` function.